# Multi level cross tab dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to find a query that can generate cross-tab output at multiple levels dynamically. I did find few solutions online that returns dynamic cross-tab results but it returns only at single level. Below is the SQL fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PopulationDetails
(
Country VARCHAR(50),
State VARCHAR(50),
Population BIGINT,
SeatsInHouse INT
)

INSERT INTO PopulationDetails
VALUES('United States','California', 38332521, 53),
('United States','Texas', 26448193, 36),
('United States','New York', 19651127, 27),
('United States','Florida', 19552860, 27),
('United States','Illinois', 12882135, 18)
```

I want my output should look like below. The number of states are not fixed and these may vary as per the requirement.

```
                                    United States               
                California      Texas       New York    Florida     Illinois
Population      38332521        26448193    19651127    19552860    12882135
SeatsInHouse    53              36          27          27          18
```

Comment: You can't really have a multi-level result like that via SQL. You;d have to do it in a presentation layer like your application or even SSRS.  The most you could do you be to have the column names have the Country in the front similar to `UnitedStates_California`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, multi-level column headers can't be done via SQL.  You'd have to format the data in a presentation layer like your application or SSRS.  If you want to get the `country` and `state` values "together", then you'd have to concatenate the names together and make that your new column names.

If you want to get the result in SQL, I'd start by concatenating the `country` and `state`, and `unpivot` the columns `population` and `SeatsInHouse` first.  The basic syntax for this process would be:

```
select 
    country_state = replace(pd.Country +'_'+pd.State, ' ', ''),
    c.col,
    c.value
from dbo.PopulationDetails pd
cross apply
(
    values
        ('Population', pd.population),
        ('SeatsInHouse', pd.SeatsInHouse)
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d42f/19/0). This gives a result:

```
|           COUNTRY_STATE |          COL |    VALUE |
|-------------------------|--------------|----------|
| UnitedStates_California |   Population | 38332521 |
| UnitedStates_California | SeatsInHouse |       53 |
|      UnitedStates_Texas |   Population | 26448193 |
|      UnitedStates_Texas | SeatsInHouse |       36 |
|    UnitedStates_NewYork |   Population | 19651127 |
|    UnitedStates_NewYork | SeatsInHouse |       27 |
```

You'll see that you now have two rows for each `Country_State` combination.  You can now pivot those `Country_State` values into columns:

```
select col, UnitedStates_California, UnitedStates_Texas, 
    UnitedStates_NewYork, UnitedStates_Florida,
    UnitedStates_Illinois
from
(
    select 
        country_state = replace(pd.Country +'_'+pd.State, ' ', ''),
        c.col,
        c.value
    from dbo.PopulationDetails pd
    cross apply
    (
        values
            ('Population', pd.population),
            ('SeatsInHouse', pd.SeatsInHouse)
    ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for country_state in (UnitedStates_California, UnitedStates_Texas, 
                            UnitedStates_NewYork, UnitedStates_Florida,
                            UnitedStates_Illinois)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d42f/20/0).

Now, if you need this done dynamically then you'd have to use dynamic SQL which creates a string that is then executed.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(country_state) 
                    from
                    (
                        select country_state = replace(Country +'_'+State, ' ', '')
                        from dbo.PopulationDetails
                    ) d
                    group by country_state
                    order by country_state
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT col, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select 
                    country_state = replace(pd.Country +''_''+pd.State, '' '', ''''),
                    c.col,
                    c.value
                from dbo.PopulationDetails pd
                cross apply
                (
                    values
                        (''Population'', pd.population),
                        (''SeatsInHouse'', pd.SeatsInHouse)
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for country_state in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d42f/21/0). Both gives a result:

```
|          COL | UNITEDSTATES_CALIFORNIA | UNITEDSTATES_FLORIDA | UNITEDSTATES_ILLINOIS | UNITEDSTATES_NEWYORK | UNITEDSTATES_TEXAS |
|--------------|-------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
|   Population |                38332521 |             19552860 |              12882135 |             19651127 |           26448193 |
| SeatsInHouse |                      53 |                   27 |                    18 |                   27 |                 36 |
```